# Cannot update score

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I was trying to make a content score as a class assignment.

Assume : (The user sees a URL and then select the checkboxes that are assigned to issues . Each issue is assigned a score in a array.)

**Whats working :**  
Individual checks are registered with their respective scores being displayed

**Whats not working :**   
Can someone help me to update the score ( as the user checks the checkbox or unchecks).

I am assuming in future if i want to increase the issues I will be able to do that since it is in an array.  (am i right)

(my week 4 in JS)

```js
//Set up an array with the respective score
var code = new Array();
code["v1"] = 1;
code["v2"] = 2;
code["v3"] = 3;
code["v4"] = 5;




// As the user selects the checkbox I want to keep on adding the score and as the user unchecks I want to recalculate and display.

function getvalueScore() {
  var score = 0;

  //Get a reference to the form 
  var theForm = document.forms["contentForm"];

  //Get a reference to the score from the "ContentForm"
  var contentScore = theForm.elements["contentScore"];


  // loop through each check box 
  for (var i = 0; i < contentScore.length; i++) {
    //if the radio button is checked
    if (contentScore[i].checked) {
      // I want to calculate and keep updating the score
      score = code[contentScore[i].value];

    }
  }
  //return score 
  return score;
}


function calculateTotal() {
  //calculation for final score 
  var scoreCard = getvalueScore();

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Your Content Score is " + scoreCard;

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Content Score</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <script src="formcalculations.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="contentForm" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">

          Content Score</br>
          <label>Please select the issues you see on the page to calculate the content score</label>
          </br>

          <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="contentScore" value="v1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />No content value</label>
          <br/>

          <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="contentScore" value="v2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Mediocre content value</label>
          <br/>

          <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="contentScore" value="v3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Obsolete content</label>
          <br/>

          <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="contentScore" value="v4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Irrelevant content</label>
          <br/>


          <br/>

          <br/>


          <div id="totalPrice"></div>


        </div>



      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--End of wrap-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the score supposed to be the total of all checked boxes?

Comment: Yes. (Sorry if this was not clear.)

Comment: Gotcha. Yup, jcubic pointed out the issue. Just need to change `score =` to `score +=` :)

Comment: thanks does this mean I need to learn more about syntax. I was in the impression that calculateTotal function would take care of that.

Comment: `+=` is just shorthand for saying `someVar = someVar + 2`. You want to total things, so you need to add them together. :)

Comment: Just curious : if I uncheck the total reduces so how is this taken care. Previously In my  crazy scared world of JS I tried (+=-) so all together plus equal and minus . I thought that should do the trick :)

Comment: Every time a checkbox is checked (or unchecked) your function runs. It loops over all of the checkboxes and adds together (totals) the values of the ones that are selected. So if you *uncheck* an input, then recalculate the total, the value will be less than before (because one fewer checkbox is checked). Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you assign last selected checkbox to score variable, so the only thing you need to do is to sum the scores with:

```
score += code[contentScore[i].value];
```